# Center of a quantum matrix algebra

Tags: reference-request, noncommutative-algebra, quantum-groups

Let $p \in k^\times$ be a nonroot of unity. It seems to be a well-known fact that the center of the quantum matrix algebra $\mathcal{O}_p(M_n(k))$ is generated by the quantum determinant $D_p$. It is not difficult to check that $D_p$ is indeed central but showing that it generates the whole center seems considerably more difficult. I'm sure this has been proved somewhere but I've been unable to track it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a proof in Section 1.5 of the paper "Finite dimensional representations of the quantum group [$GL_q(n; C)$ and the zonal spherical functions on $U_q(n-1)\setminus U_q(n)$"](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/math1924/19/1/19_1_31/_article) by Noumi, Yamada and Mimachi, Japanese Journal of Mathematics (New Series), Vol 19 (1993) no 1.  p 31-80.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. It seems perhaps that their proof was not the first. The authors reference another paper before giving their own proof, but that paper is in Russian.

Comment: Indeed. I'm a little curious whether or not it's the same proof.